# System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a while loop, that I want my program to run through while a user has a form active. right now I have tried both,

```
While frmLineProduct.ActiveForm.Focus = True
While (frmLineProduct.ActiveForm.Equals(True))
```

But neither of these work. I am going to keep reading on this but if someone has already knows how to do this, I would appreciate the lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being a method that I hadn't heard of before, but someone in one of my other posts led me onto it.

Control.Invoke Method (Delegate, Object())

To anyone who is interested the answer can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a couple of events to control the status, for example:

```
Public Property HasFocus As Boolean = True 'global flag

Private Sub Form_Deactivated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Deactivated
    _hasFocus = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Activated
    _hasFocus = True
End Sub
```

Then in your code:

```
While Form.Hasfocus
    Application.DoEvents 'a work-around for receiving events while in a while
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm still a novice, so I need to ask. My loop won't actually be in the form.vb code but in a different class. So can I replace the Me.LostFocus and Me.GotFocus, with FormName.LostFocus and FormName.GotFocus?

Comment: A form very rarely gets the Got/LostFocus events, its child controls do.  Use the Activated and Deactivated events instead.  The While cannot work, events can only fire when the UI thread goes idle.

Comment: Brandon: you can make the value a public property instead and then access it from you class. Hans: true, let me update events. Application.DoEvents is of course an option, but..